# Wikitude SDK for iOS crashing on iOS 9 Device

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, augmented-reality, wikitude

I want to code an app with augmented reality support by Wikitude. For that I use the native SDK for iOS from [Wikitude](http://www.wikitude.com/download). Setup and everything works, like it is described on their website/[documentation](http://www.wikitude.com/developer/documentation/iosnative).
When I run the app from Xcode on my iDevice, the app launches and crashes immediately with the following error:

```
  dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftSecurity.dylib
  Referenced from:/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/some-number/App.app/Frameworks/WikitudeNativeSDK.framework/WikitudeNativeSDK
  Reason: image not found
```

I have googled my way through the web now, still no solution found about how to fix this problem/bug/whateverthismightbe. I cleaned the whole project, removed the DerivedData-Files, restarted Xcode, nothing works.

My setup is: OS X 10.11, Xcode 7.0.1, iOS 9.0.2

Maybe someone had this problem too and solved it, would be nice to know!

Thanks in advice.